# python create a data frame with one row by a list (Nice way without "reshape" )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume  we have data, and columnNames e.g. dataExample = [1,2] columnNames = ['a','b']
we want to create a python dataframe like:

```
    a   b
0   1   2
```

Surprsingly, writting

```
df = pd.DataFrame( dataExample  , columns  = columnNames  )
```

gives  error, since data (i.e. [1,2]) is shaped like (2,1) and columns requires shape (1,2)

So the way round can be

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.array([1,2]).reshape(1,-1)  , columns  = ['a','b'] )
```

It works,  but, it seems not quite "nice"/"one-line" as I naively expect the answer should be.

**Question:**

is there some "nice"/"shorter" way ?

---

Another way to do the same, but still not "nice"/"one line"

```
df = pd.DataFrame( columns  = ['a','b'], index = [0] )
df.loc[0] = [1,2]
```

But again it does not look like "nice"/"short" as I would expect

---

There is related question:

[python create a data frame with one row by a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079408/python-create-a-data-frame-with-one-row-by-a-list)

But it does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list of list`:

```
dataExample = [1,2] 
columnNames = ['a','b']
df = pd.DataFrame( [dataExample]  , columns  = columnNames  )
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
```